# Averaging z scores when doing a "group by"

Tags: dataset, normalization, group-differences, mean

I have a dataset where each row is an hourly measurement of certain fields (columns). For each column I then add another column that is its respective *z* score relative to the entire population.

If I then group by month by calculating the aggregate mean for all merging rows, are my *z* scores still valid, or do I need to recalculate the *z* score for each month?

**EDIT**

I realize I wasn't clear enough in my question. I have a dataset like this of hourly weather measurements going back several years:

[image]

In panda I groupby and average each respective hour (So I average and group all the Jan 1st 2pm rows over all years... etc.)

```
df['hour'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda t: "%d-%d-%d" % (t.month, t.day,t.hour))
g = np.round(df.groupby('hour').mean(),decimals=4).reset_index()
```

which returns this:

[image]

I then merge the grouped dataframe (g) onto the original df adding a column for each avg, reset the index to be of Date, and drop the 'hour' column from the grouped df:

```
new_df = pd.merge(left=df, right=g, on='hour', suffixes=('','_avg') )
new_df.set_index('Date').drop('hour',axis=1,inplace=False).head()
```

This returns:

[image]

What I would like however is to also add a "z score" column for each respective month/day/hour using the standard deviation of the entire population. I'm actually now sure how to do this but I think it would be similar to how the other "_avg" columns were computed.

Assuming that is all possible and each row-hour has additional z-score columns for each metric this finally leads me to my original question...

Later on outside the context of python/panda let's say I take only one year of the data, groupby month, and aggregate by mean. Will those averaged z scores by month still be representative of the original entire population?

For example let's say I took the averages of June 2011 and found the temperature z-score to be 1.2. Can I say that the average temperature of June 2011 was 1.2 standard deviations away from the normal (total population) mean?

Comment: Are you *z*-scoring using the population standard deviation? If not, aggregated data will have a different standard deviation than the raw data, so that would change your statistics (which are technically *t*-statistics when using the sample *SD*).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but this reminds me of the distinction between grand-mean centering and group-mean centering... in any case, I think the answer to your question might depend on what you're going to do with those scores in the first place. (Again, I'm not sure I understand your question.)

Comment: @PatrickCoulombe thanks for the question! I've updated my question significantly.. Let me know if that is still confusing.

Comment: @NickStauner It would be for the entire population.. .I've updated my question as well.